# Swift Label время

Tags: swift, дата, ui, swift4, label

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в Label выводилась дата сегодняшнего дня. Саму функцию для со даты написал. Не могу понять, как встроить в UIcontroller?

```
@IBOutlet weak var CurrentDateLabel: UILabel!//Мой Label
func CurrentDate(){
    let date = Date()

    let MonthFormat = DateFormatter()
    MonthFormat.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let Month = MonthFormat.string(from: date)

    let DayYearFormat = DateFormatter()
    DayYearFormat.dateFormat = "dd/yyyy"
    let DayYear = DayYearFormat.string(from: date)
    let DateArgument = (Month + "\n" + DayYear)
    CurrentDateLabel.text = DateArgument
}
```

Ошибки нет, но ничего не выводит

Comment: Можете добавить в текст вопроса код функции, которая возвращает необходимую дату?

Comment: В каком методе вы вызываете CurrentDate()?

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

var timeString = "Дата: \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))"
label1.text = timeString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Создаем текущую дату
let date = Date()
// Создаем и настраиваем форматор дат
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy" // формат даты для вывода
```

В подборе формата даты тебе может помочь этот [сервис](http://nsdateformatter.com/)

```
//получаем строку из даты через formatter
var dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

youLabel.text = dateString
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем `UIViewController` в методе `viewDidLoad()` напишите:

```
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100))
    label.text = "Date property"
    view.addSubview(label)
```